# ‘_snprintf’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, printf

I am working on a ffmepg c++ project which links a hpp file, in the hpp file:

```
#define snprintf _snprintf
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
include <assert.h>

#if defined _MSC_VER && _MSC_VER >= 1200
#pragma warning( disable: 4244 4510 4512 4610 4146 4996 4005)

#define sprintf sprintf_s
#define _sprintf _sprintf_s
#define _snprintf _snprintf_s

#endif  


snprintf (oc->filename, sizeof(oc->filename), "%s", filename);
```

it gives the error:

```
‘_snprintf’ was not declared in this scope
```

It is quite weird the error shows **‘_snprintf’** while what I use is **'snprint'**. This code is wrote by others, I did not understand these **#define** he used. If i remove the line **#define sprintf sprintf_s**, it gives error:

```
segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Due to ffmpeg is incompatible with C++, I have include the **stdio.h** and **cstdio** both within **extern C** and out of **extern C**, but the error continue show out. What is the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first change this line

```
include <assert.h>
```

with:

```
#include <assert.h>
```

and write this line

```
#define snprintf _snprintf
```

after includes and try compiling code